# How to add header directory to C++ using CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: opencv, cmake, kinect, openni, point-cloud-library

I have configured OpenNI+PCL+OpenCV with CMakeLists.txt. I didn't write it myself. Just copied fragments of PCL documentation, OpenCV manual and some code I found to integrate OpenNI into one project. I'm able to build it and successfully find all includes & libs. The problem comes when OpenNI samples use GL/glut.h or GLES, or opengles.h . I  can't understand how to add that  includes to my project with cmake.

My commands to build:

```
>projectDir/build/cmake ..
>projectDir/build/make
>projectDir/build/./project
```

projectDir has `GLES/` `GL/`

[CMakeLists.txt](http://pastie.org/private/appbpa6uv93a5wbxuubvaw) which will help many beginner people with OpenNI+PCL+OpenCV.

Comment: I don't see any targets for OpenNI samples in your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: well, because  I'm currently working with my project. I know that I should change the target and project name. But it's not the question. I am asking about what lines I need to add CMakeLists.txt to be able build and find GL/headers...

Comment: These lines are already present - `INCLUDE(FindOpenGL REQUIRED)` and `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})`.

Comment: OK, this is to find globally installed GL. But what if in the samples code is the #include <GL/gl.h> ? How to add the include custom dir to CMAKE ?

Comment: `But what if in the samples code is the #include <GL/gl.h> ?` The compiler would pickup this header from that globally installed GL. `How to add the include custom dir to CMAKE ?` Same way as you added global ones: `include_directories(your/local/dir)`.